# loop over specific observation and save as output file

Tags: r

Is it possible to loop through specific observation with a function then save the output? I wrote a function that requires two variables, 1) dataset to do calculations; 2) subject number.

For example, the data frame here has data for two subjects. I wish to loop over the dataframe to calculate the mean for each subject and have the output for each subject.

```
df1<-data.frame(data= c(2,3,4,5), subject= c("S2","S1","S2","S1"))

for (i in df1) {
if df1$subject== i
subset_(i)<-mean(data)
}
```

Can anyone help me to improve the codes, please?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(data, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(data~ subject, df1, mean)
#   subject data
#1      S1    4
#2      S2    3
```